# How to sync specific files with unison?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, unison

I originally [posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462906/how-to-sync-specific-files-with-unison) but i realized this might be more suited here. I'm using [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/) on Linux (Manjaro) to keep some files synced between two local folders but I'm running into a problem.

I have a main notes folder which looks like this and has a lot of text files I write and export to PDF.

`my-notes/file1.pdf... file150.pdf`

I'd like to have some of these notes sent to another, more structured folder which I push to git.

```
organized-notes/
|
|------------------ Subject1/file34.pdf, file37.pdf
|
|------------------ Subject2/file11.pdf, file121.pdf
|
|------------------ Subject3/file97.pdf
|
|------------------ .git/
```

The issue is that unison works well between two directories or folders but I'm breaking down my files per subject and I would like them to be synced only in the relevant sub-folder. Also, I don't want to send all my notes to this more organized folder, only the specific ones I do select.

Right now, anytime I make a change I have to `cd` to the relevant subject folder and use unison in there, like this `unison ~/my-notes/file34.pdf file34.pdf`. This is of course very annoying and I'd like to automate it.

How I can fix this either with unison or another tool?

Comment: Unison is definitely designed for *mass* synchronization of files, and not so much for this sort of use. (Like, I'm baffled why you don't want to just sync all your notes files and run unison on the top-level directory each time). So Unison is kinda overkill here. Maybe something more primitive like scp or rsync that you wrap in a script?

Comment: As for automating things, how could your automatic procedure know which files you want to sync? At some point you have to manually specify to sync only certain files.

Comment: My personal notes directory is a private repo and my organized-notes directory is another (public) repo, which I share with others. I'd like to sync changes like this : my-notes -> organized-notes. Then I can push the organized-notes repo to gitlab. I just can't seem to find a good way to do this.